# Alter Odoo XmlRPC context to use a specific language

Tags: python, odoo, xml-rpc, odoo-10

I need to get the translated data from odoo with a specific language using XMLRPC 
by default odoo sends data in the default language which is English

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'res.country', 'search_read', [[]], {'fields': ['name']})
```

how to add context to this request to use a specific translation language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

let's say the endpoint is api
you just need to add the param context as shown in the following code

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'res.country', 'search_read', [[]], {'fields': ['id', 'name'], 'context' :{'lang': "fr_FR"}})
```

Answer (score 7):

Here I have listed some example syntax for xmlrpc(Odoo Web Service API) common ORM methods to add context as a param.

## Create

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'create', [{'name: Atul'}], {'context' :{'tag': 1}})
```

## Search

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'search_read', [[('name', '=', "Atul")]], {'context' :{'tag': 1}})
```

## Search Read

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'search_read', [[('name', '=', "Atul")]], {'fields': ['id', 'name'], 'context' :{'tag': 1}})
```

## Read

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'read', [ids], {'context' :{'tag': 1}})
```

## Write

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'write', [[id], {'name': "Atul Arvind"}], {'context' :{'tag': 1}})
```

## Unlink

```
api.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'unlink', [[id]], {'context' :{'tag': 1})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To complete @karara-mohamed answer, here what it looks like in a complete JSON-RPC API call (`/jsonrpc`):

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "call",
    "params": {
        "service": "object",
        "method": "execute_kw",
        "args": [
            "<database-name>",
            <user_id>,
            "<user_password>",
            "product.product",
            "search_read",
            [
                [
                   ["type", "=", "product"]
                ]
            ],
            {
                "fields": ["id", "name", "display_name"],
                "context": {
                    "lang": "fr_FR"
                },
                "limit": 5
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": <idRequest>
}
```